# Get added and removed words between two strings

Tags: python, diff

Given two strings, I'd like to be able to -- in Python -- be able to determine which words have been added and which words have been removed between the two. I've seen difflib, but apparently it cannot do it.

For example: given 'hello my name is' and 'hello my guys is', it would return ['guys'] as added words, and ['name'] as removed words. Thanks a lot.

EDIT: Probably the example I gave wasn't the best. It should also work without spaces between the current text and the new text. Maybe using difflib to get all the new sections, and then split with regexp "\b". I'll give it a try.

Comment: What's the desired output for `"Hello world"` and `"world Hello"`?

Comment: Can you give any more examples such as the one suggested?

Comment: If your example "wasn't the best", then please improve it? A listing of expected input vs expected output is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't particularly pretty but seems to work for most cases I can think of.  I'm sure this can be tidied up a lot too and should be easy to make case insensitive.

```
def freqs(list):
    words = {}
    for word in list:
        words[word] = words.get(word, 0) + 1
    return words

def added_and_removed(a, b):
    af = freqs(a.split())
    bf = freqs(b.split())

    removed = []
    added = []

    for key in af:
        num = bf.get(key)
        if num == None:
            if af[key] > 1:
                words = [key]*af[key]
                removed.extend(words)
            else:
                removed.append(key)

    for key in bf:
        num = af.get(key)
        if num == None:
            added.append(key)
        elif num > 1:
            words = [key]*(num-1)
            removed.extend(words)

    return added, removed

a = 'hello hello hello my name is Dave dave bar foo'
b = 'hello my guys is test easy rob dave beef foo'     

added, removed =  added_and_removed(a, b)
print added
print removed
```

gives

```
['beef', 'rob', 'easy', 'test', 'guys']
['bar', 'name', 'Dave', 'hello', 'hello']
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to remember about python is that it has "batteries included". This means that you should look in the standard library for a tool to do what you need, before re-inventing it yourself.

A more powerful technique is to re-use the [difflib.SequenceMatcher](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-examples) to look for differences in strings. Example:

```
import difflib

before = 'hello my name is'
after = 'hello my guys is'

def isjunk(string):
    "Return True if we don't care about this string"
    return string == ' '


s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk)
s.set_seqs(before, after)

for (
        opcode,
        before_start, before_end,
        after_start, after_end
) in s.get_opcodes():
    if opcode == 'equal':
        # We don't care.
        continue

    print "%7s '%s' -> '%s'" % (
            opcode,
            before[before_start:before_end],
            after[after_start:after_end],
    )
```

This produces this output, which can obviously be customized to do exactly what you need:

```
replace 'name' -> 'guys'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
before = "hello my name is"
after = "hello my  guy is test"


before = before.split(' ')
after = after.split(' ')

for item in after:
    if not item in before:
        print item
```